# Distance between two vector lines in each east-west raster row (in QGIS)

Tags: qgis-3, distance, rasterization, vectorization

I have 2m-resolution raster LiDAR data of a marsh edge from two moments in time and I am trying to calculate how much the marsh has "retreated" between the datasets.

I used the LiDAR data to draw vector lines where the marsh edge is, which you can see in my screenshot below.

[image]

I am interested in, for each East-West row of the original raster data, what the distance between these two vector lines is. Ultimately, I want a vector/table of distances between the marsh edge lines for each row of the original raster data.

I have each vector line as a shapefile right now.

[Euclidean Distance between two lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139940/euclidean-distance-between-two-lines) was close but was seeking the "closest" point rather than a perfect East-West distance.

Any advice on how to do this? Should I rasterize the vectors first? (was trying this but haven't gotten rasterize to work yet) Maybe there is an easy way in python?

I am running QGIS 3.16.2 with GRASS.